# Ignore the CERTIFICATE_ERROR using CPP REST SDK

Tags: c++, ssl, https, visual-c++-2013, cpprest-sdk

I have been using the [CPP Rest SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/) for my application which serves as both HTTP_Client and HTTP_Server as well. And now I want to support HTTPS in my application.

The HTTP_Client will be running in HTTP and HTTP_Server will be running as HTTPS.

Since there is no authentication needed from Client side :

**I just want to ignore the** `CERTIFICATE_ERROR`

But I couldn't find any such option in the CPP REST SDK.

Please help, I need to know how to ignore

Note: I use Visual Studio 2013 for my application

Answer (score 6):

There is **config.validate_certificates** @ [src/http/client/http_client_asio.cpp#L166](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/500f7a2224c1ac3fca8980ee8afe87884b8f7ccb/Release/src/http/client/http_client_asio.cpp#L166)

```
http_client_config config;
config.set_validate_certificates(false);
http_client client(url, config);
```

Comment: @AgileMystery good :) ...please remember to mark the question as solved